Declaring a cursor in plpgsql fails
I wrote a db function for plpgsql (postgre) in supabase.
When declaring a cursor I always get ERROR: 42P01: relation "cursor1" does not exist.
This is how I declare it:
DECLARE
    cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT public.spending_cap.cap, public.spending_cap.spent, public.spending_cap.image_cap, public.spending_cap.image_spent, public.spending_cap.id, public.spending_cap.created_by FROM public.spending_cap, public.user_profile WHERE is_parent = true AND public.user_profile.id = public.spending_cap.created_by AND organisation is NULL;
    entry cursor1%rowtype;

I am just declaring cursor1 how can it say that the relation does not exist? If I just execute the SELECT statement, I get results. I use this declared cursor to loop over the same SELECT statement.
Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

You cannot use %rowtype with a cursor, I guess.

@LaurenzAlbe Hm here they use it.

'Here' is pl/sql in Oracle not pl/pgsql in Postgres. See the rowtype for Postgres.

Slightly offtopic: Why do you want a cursor? It's hardly needed in PL/pgSQL, it's already using a cursor internally. What problem that you face, should it solve?

Take a look at 43.6.6. Looping through Query Results and 43.7. Cursors. You can declare a record variable then give it as the iterator in a for loop over the query directly to get an implicit cursor. %rowtype is for tables, composite types and views.

PL/pgSQL doesn't allow %ROWTYPE on cursor variables. The engine of PL/pgSQL is very different from Oracle and it is just out of concept of PL/pgSQL. Probably should not be hard to implement this feature, but it is out of concept. You should to use RECORD type instead:
DECLARE
    cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT public.spending_cap.cap, public.spending_cap.spent, public.spending_cap.image_cap, public.spending_cap.image_spent, public.spending_cap.id, public.spending_cap.created_by FROM public.spending_cap, public.user_profile WHERE is_parent = true AND public.user_profile.id = public.spending_cap.created_by AND organisation is NULL;
    entry record;

Try to read related documentation. Although the syntax is similar sometimes, in details there are lot of differences between  PL/pgSQL cursors and PL/SQL cursors.
